# android.util.Base64 encoded String too short

Tags: java, android, base64, encode

I am using android.util.Base64 and want to encode a bitmap to a base64-string, but it is always too short. For instance an online tool says, it has an invalid length and compared to an valid one it is surely too short.

This is my code:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Here is an example of the different length of the strings:

[My string](http://pastebin.com/c1qU7czu)

[valid string](http://pastebin.com/t3KSSbP3)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine but you can verify it by using this code:

```
byte[] b2 = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
boolean equals = Arrays.equals(b, b2);
```

If the two arrays have equal contents then the problem is not on the Base64 but in the way that you're using the `encodedImage` string. Remember that things like LogCat might truncate strings that exceed a certain length, so make sure that you print out the length of the `encodedImage` string and compare it to the Base64 you've got.

Also, Base64 encoded strings are 4/3 (133%) longer than the original, so if the ByteArrayOutputStream has length 9000, your base64 string is expected to have length 12000.